# Building from quilljs source succeeds, but Quill is not found when referenced

Tags: javascript, webpack, quill

I have managed to build quilljs from source following the steps outlined in the quilljs github repo and from the quilljs documentation. The quill version is 1.3.6. The npm run build succeeds with no errors. The problem is that whenever i want to use the built package, the module Quill is not found (like it usually does when you reference a prebuilt version from a CDN).

I have used the minimal webpack example found on the github repo. And have installed all the dependents using npm install. I have also made sure that webpack has been installed properly as per documentation. Since this didnt work, I have also tried upgrading to the newest webpack versions and newest version of typescript, ts-loader and html-loader to no avail. I still get the same issue that it cannot find Quill.

However as stated, the build succeeds with no errors or warnings.

The entry point code for the build is (using the example provided in the repo):

```
import Quill from "quill/core";
import Toolbar from "quill/modules/toolbar";
import Snow from "quill/themes/snow";

import Bold from "quill/formats/bold";
import Italic from "quill/formats/italic";
import Header from "quill/formats/header";

Quill.register({
  "modules/toolbar": Toolbar,
  "themes/snow": Snow,
  "formats/bold": Bold,
  "formats/italic": Italic,
  "formats/header": Header
});

export default Quill;
```

the webpack config file (slightly modified to export the final bundle file to my app location)

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./app.js"),

  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "../../quill_app/dist/quill.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      parchment: path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        "node_modules/parchment/src/parchment.ts"
      ),
      quill$: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/quill/quill.js")
    },
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".svg"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["es2015"]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: {
              compilerOptions: {
                declaration: false,
                target: "es5",
                module: "commonjs"
              },
              transpileOnly: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
              minimize: false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

the index.html to run Quill from:

```
<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br /></p>
</div>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="quill.js"></script>
<script src="code.js" type="module"></script>
<!-- Initialize Quill editor --
```

>

with the javascript part of it:

```
var quill = new Quill("#editor", {
  theme: "snow"
});
```

**expected result:** Runs quill as normal and shows the UI

**actual result:** No quill is displayed. Console gives: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Quill is not defined".

Has anyone besides the devs managed to do a build based on the provided docs? It does seem a long time since the docs for the build process has been updated, but i guess not much has changed except for newer versions of the dependencies?

Comment: I do not find something wrong in your code above and unfortunately do not have time to debug it, but I can confirm you that on our project we rely on the native Quill source and build it/extend it without any significant problems.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem like a bug with Quill. Our team was able to resolve this issue by using the ProvidePlugin in our webpack.config to teach Webpack about how to resolve Quill.

import the ProvidePlugin in your webpack.config

```
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
```

then make use of the plugin within the plugins section of the config - see below for an example

```
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: '...',
  output: {
   ...
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
       ...
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
  /// other plugins here 

    new ProvidePlugin({
            "Quill": "quill"
        }),
  ]
};
```

you can read more about plugins here: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/plugins/